# TwitchLib Help- Work around old TwitchClient() method

Tags: c#, twitch

I was watching a tutorial on how to script a bot using C# and the instructor used (to my knowledge) an old call to TwitchClient which takes credentials and references. However, it is currently not the case and I'm wondering now what might be a good way to work around it. Currently, the method takes a websocket and logger but I have suspicion that you still need to use credentials and references.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here's the video with the timestamp: https://youtu.be/5f1T9hQqJps?t=8m3s

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the single line in the video, these two lines should now achieve mostly the same effect:

```
client = new TwitchClient();
client.Initialize(credentials, "channel");
```

If you want to also enable logging (like in the video), then you will need to provide an instance of `ILogger` to the first call like so:

```
client = new TwitchClient(null, myLoggingInstance);
```

The WebSocket parameter is used for testing (so you can generate your own traffic to test your bot), the docs advise not to set this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. One more thing, when you say "need to provide an instance of ILogger to the first call like so: ..." do you mean instead of client = new TwitchClient(); I use client = new TwitchClient(null, myLoggingInstance); or do you mean below that call?

Comment: I mean instead of. You will need to add a reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` to create the logger you pass in.

Answer (score 0):

its quite simple actually, even the github page shows a simple example:

```
ConnectionCredentials credentials = new ConnectionCredentials("twitch_username", "access_token");
var clientOptions = new ClientOptions
{
    MessagesAllowedInPeriod = 750,
    ThrottlingPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
};
WebSocketClient customClient = new WebSocketClient(clientOptions);
client = new TwitchClient(customClient);
client.Initialize(credentials, "channel");
client.OnLog += Client_OnLog;
client.Connect();
```

then later declare this function:

```
private void Client_OnLog(object sender, OnLogArgs e)
{
Console.WriteLine($"{e.DateTime.ToString()}: {e.BotUsername} - {e.Data}");
}
```